# Fabric to copy the File from local host to multiple remote hosts

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to copy a file from my local fabric system to the multiple remote hosts using `fabric` `put` command, So, when I ran it doesn't complain anything but it does not copy the file.

Secondly, I see my remote Server already has the file, may that be an issue here? below the code.

```
import sys
from fabric.api import env
from fabric.operations import run, put

env.skip_bad_hosts=True
env.command_timeout=160
env.user = 'jaggle'
env.shell = "/bin/sh -c"
env.warn_only = True
env.password = '!@heyNaSaFreak'
use_sudo = True
def readhost():
    env.hosts = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]

def copyLDAP():
    put("/Karn/ldap.conf","/etc/ldap.conf", use_sudo = True)
```

Below is output of the run ...

```
$ echo "tt-server01" | fab readhost -f OpenDgCopy.py copyLDAP
[tt-server0] Executing task 'copyLDAP'
[tt-server0] put: /Karn/ldap.conf -> /etc/ldap.conf

Done.
Disconnecting from tt-server0... done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `readhost` task, you can directly use the `-H` option with a comma-separated list of hosts:

`fab -f OpenDgCopy.py copyLDAP -H tt-server0,tt-sever1`

According to the documentation of `put`:

> As with the OpenSSH `sftp` program, `.put` will overwrite
>   pre-existing remote files without requesting confirmation.